# Excel insert cell value within string

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have this formula:

```
=GetElementByRegex(H2,"<a href=""/testpage/Field/Index/15"">([^""]*?)</a>")
```

and I would like to replace `15` with a cell value e.g. `J2` but i don't seem to figure it out how to add this correctly into the string.

Would appriciate help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
"<a href=""/testpage/Field/Index/" & J2 & """>([^<]*)</a>"
```

instead of `"<a href=""/testpage/Field/Index/15"">([^""]*?)</a>"`.

Probably you also want to replace `([^""]*?)` with `([^<]*)` as `[^<]*` matches 0+ chars other than `<`.